# Drag an object in a box

Tags: html, jquery-animate, createjs

I'm having a problem constraining the moving of an object in a box.
It works a little near but when I press my object (_this.perso) there is a jump that is created (the cursor of my mouse is shifted compared to my character ..) and I can not move it at the end of my sliderBoundary object.

```
_this = this;
stage.enableMouseOver();
createjs.Touch.enable(stage);
_this.perso.cursor = "pointer";

//XY
var bounds = {x:150, y:90, width:1600, height: 600};  

//REC
var sliderBoundary = new createjs.Shape();    
sliderBoundary.graphics.beginStroke("#999").setStrokeStyle(2).drawRect(bounds.x, bounds.y, bounds.width, bounds.height);  
this.stage.addChild(sliderBoundary);    
//sliderBoundary.alpha=0;

//D&G
_this.perso.addEventListener("pressmove", dragCon);  
function dragCon(evt) {  
    evt.currentTarget.x = Math.max(bounds.x, Math.min(bounds.x + bounds.width, evt.stageX));
}  

_this.perso.x = bounds.x;  
_this.perso.y = bounds.y + bounds.height / 2;
```

[Here is a link of the animation](http://c2iblog.fr/cj/proto.html)

Thank you for your help,
Matthieu

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty straightforward solution:

1. Measure the distance between the mouse and the object when you press down
2. Offset the new position by that amount.

EaselJS has nice `localX` and `localY` properties on mouse events, which automatically give you a `globalToLocal()` on the mouse event so that you know where in the current target the object was pressed. You can store these values to use as the offset:

```
var offset = new createjs.Point();
perso.addEventListener("mousedown", function(e) {
    offset.setValues(e.localX, e.localY);
});
```

Note that I used a Point with `setValues`, since it is a little cleaner than an object with x/y props.

Then just subtract that value from the stageX when you do your pressMove

```
function dragCon(evt) {  
    var x = evt.stageX - offset.x;
    evt.currentTarget.x = Math.max(bounds.x, Math.min(bounds.x + bounds.width, x));
}
```

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3my1wn4v/

Hope that helps!